# What I am depends on you, yet you have no control over what I am.

Tags: riddle

> I am big or small,
>   tall or short,
>   soft or hard,
>   cold or hot,
>   yet I am devoid of a physical shape.
>   What I am depends on you,
>   yet you have no control over what I am.
>   Whatever you make me out to be,
>   perhaps your neighbor will disagree.

What am I?

Comment: Seems broad...  Could be a lot of different conceptual things couldn't it?  from "a building carved into a mushroom" to "my imaginary friend" to "a mystical, magical, elemental elf"

Comment: @BrentHackers Don't forget that it is devoid of a physical shape. and what it is depend on you.

Comment: My imaginary friend is non-physical and what it is definitely depends on me...

Comment: @BrentHackers Will your neighbor disagree about what your imaginary friend is like? Is your friend hot, cold and hard?

Comment: My neighbour would see nothing where I saw my friend.  You said hot OR cold and soft OR hard which imaginary friends could be... (at least in your mind which seems valid given that you're describing something that sounds non-corporeal)

Answer (score 2):

I hope the evidence below are enough to support that it could be:

> Opinion

*I am big or small, tall or short*

> Our opinion about something could either be lengthy, if we know the subject well or very short if we know practically nothing about the subject.

*soft or hard, cold or hot*

> One could characterise an opinion as being either common or extreme.

*yet I am devoid of a physical shape*

> Our opinion is not a physical object, it is in our brain's neural network.

*What I am depends on you, yet you have no control over what I am*

> One could study a subject well to be able to form their own opinion around it, but sometimes we don't choose our opinion since it can be shaped by our environment and experiences.

*Whatever you make me out to be, perhaps your neighbour will disagree*

> Most of the times there will be people disagreeing with us, and that person could be someone we know and/or talk to every day

But as mentioned in the comments, this is a very broad riddle, it could be a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to fit:

> your feelings?

I am big or small,
tall or short,
soft or hard,
cold or hot,

> Feelings can be characterized as being big, small (i like you a little/lot), soft, hard (soft-hearted or hard-hearted), cold or hot (hot tempered, cold as ice stoicness).
>  I'm not sure about the tall or short part

yet I am devoid of a physical shape.

> Feelings have no shape (unless its in the pixar movie Inside Out)

What I am depends on you,

> Feelings depends on the person feeling them. Multiple people can go through the same situation and feel different things, or have different intensities of feelings

yet you have no control over what I am.

> People can't control their feelings, they can control their actions, but feelings just happen. #beingHuman

Whatever you make me out to be,

> People express their feelings in different ways

perhaps your neighbor will disagree

> People tend to judge other's for what they feel and how it affects their decisions

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are:

> Everything

I am big or small,

> Everything is big or small

tall or short,
soft or hard,
cold or hot,

> Same goes for above

yet I am devoid of a physical shape.

> 'Everything' doesn't really have a physical form

What I am depends on you,

> It means differently to everyone

yet you have no control over what I am.
Whatever you make me out to be,

> Wish you have control over everything!

perhaps your neighbor will disagree.

> Oh yeah.. on everything